# How to put a drawing over text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to build a cover page with some tilted listing in background and a tikz picture on top, but I can't center it.  The background is created by:

```
\begin{turn}{30}
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{turn}
```

and the foreground picture with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0) -- (3,3) -- cycle node [draw,rectangle,midway] {some very complex drawing};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The question is how to put the picture over the rotated listing , in the middle of the page?

Also is it possible to move the rotated text over the page (left/right, top/bottom), or even make it wider?

I've tried to surround the listing with`\tikzmark` and then to get the middle by `( $(pic cs:start)!0.5!(pic cs:end)$ )` but because of the rotation and shifting it goes far away from the center of the page.

Comment: Try putting the listing in a node in the tikzpicture.

Comment: You may try `package pgf` and `\node at (current page.center){some drawing}`.

Comment: Adding to c_bfx's comment: you may want to put the drawing *and* the listing in a node each and place both nodes at the center of the page using `current page.center`.